# detect presentedViewController at runtime

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, ios5

Looking through the iOS 5 documentation I noticed that modalViewController was deprecated in place of presentedViewController.  I thought of using:

```
[viewController respondsToSelector:@selector(presentedViewController)];
```

To see if the getter was present and use presentedViewController when it's support.

Is this the correct way of detecting this functionality in iOS5+? or is there a better way?

Comment: If you are writing new code and if your base line is iOS 5 already, you don't have to test for the presence at all. The method is there. Only if you have a project, where you need to support iOS 4 in the same binary, you have to perform the test (and the way to test you gave will work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the containment code is private on iOS4 meaning that just checking with respondsToSelector might not always work. I'm not 100% sure if it will fail in your case but I would still recommend to check if the current version is iOS5 or higher. It is a more robust and future proof way to make sure you are not using iOS5-specific code in an earlier version.

```
float version = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
```

Comment: That would work for 5.0, 5.1 which in my case would be fine, however would that work for something like 4.3.3 or a 5.1.1? I could parse the string and do some logic there worst case.

Comment: The systemVersion property is an NSString which means you should be able to string-match it with 4.3.3 and 5.1.1. So, yes, it should work for those versions aswell.